# SKCropNode fails to crop a child SKEffectNode with a filter going

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, crop

Maybe this makes sense but I noticed that if you have a SKEffectNode as child of a SKCropNode, the cropping does NOT work at all if said SKEffectNode has its filter set to something.

Specifically I am using a blur CIFilter on the SKEffectNode. I made a toggle button in-game so I could turn on/off the blur effect, and it's very apparent that SKCropNode can't crop blurred things. I'm wondering if this would also apply to most/all other CIFilter.

Btw the way I turn on blur is like this:

```
SKEffectNode* nodetoblur = [self thenodetoblur];
CIFilter *blur = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur" keysAndValues:@"inputRadius", @10.0f, nil];
nodetoblur.filter = blur;
nodetoblur.shouldEnableEffects = YES;
```

And off:

```
SKEffectNode* nodetoblur = [self thenodetoblur];
nodetoblur.filter = nil;
nodetoblur.shouldRasterize = NO;
nodetoblur.shouldEnableEffects = NO;
```

Can anyone explain the theory behind this inefficiency of SKCropNode, and possibly a workaround?

...maybe I should make the SKCropNode child of the SKEffectNode, instead of the (current) other way around.

Update: The culprit seems to be that an SKEffectNode is created with `shouldEnableEffects` set to YES. It has to be set to NO, or the SKEffectNode cannot be cropped by SKCropNode.

Comment: My attempt to crop a `SK3DNode` using a `SKCropNode` also didn't work. I assume it has something to do with drawing into separate buffers that `SKCropNode` doesn't cope well with.